# How to Override Maximize Button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, overriding, maximize

I want to override maximize button of window in WPF to resize width and height more than one monitor.
How to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Is this for your app or somebody else's?  In other words are you planning to make something like Ultramon?

Comment: this's for my app, now I have dual monitor.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/10d17bde-dfae-4c0f-bf86-b7832a87475d/how-to-catch-maximizing-event?forum=wpf

Comment: but it's just catch maximizing event, can't resize width, height for window :)

Comment: That's why it's _not an answer_ but a comment.  It should get you one step closer

Comment: @MickyD okay thank you :), I'm trying to find an answer. It's so hard!

Answer (score 2):

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035623/9912441

You need to find total width and height of all monitor with the monitor info.

```
[DllImport("user32")]
internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hMonitor, MONITORINFO lpmi);

[DllImport("User32")]
internal static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr handle, int flags);

/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public class MONITORINFO
{
     /// <summary>
     /// </summary>            
     public int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MONITORINFO));

     /// <summary>
     /// </summary>            
     public RECT rcMonitor = new RECT();

     /// <summary>
     /// </summary>            
     public RECT rcWork = new RECT();

     /// <summary>
     /// </summary>            
     public int dwFlags = 0;
}

void Maximize(HWND hWnd, HMONITOR hMonitor)
{
    // access monitor info
    MONITORINFO monitorInfo = { sizeof(MONITORINFO) };
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monitorInfo);

    // restore window to normal size if it is not yet
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);

    // move window to the monitor
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, nullptr, monitorInfo.rcMonitor.left, 
    monitorInfo.rcMonitor.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);

    // maximize window
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);    
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a small demo code of this?. Just press maximize button and cover dual monitor. Thanks!

Comment: @MickyD yeah yeah, I'm sorry!